# "Memory Leak" with grequests?

Tags: python, gevent, python-requests

This is a stripped down version of the script that causes continually increasing memory usage, I've seen it go past 600MB after 2 minutes:

```
import requests
import grequests

lines = (grequests.get(l.strip(), timeout=15) for l in open('links.txt') if len(l.strip()))

for r in grequests.imap(lines, size=20):
    if r.ok:
        print r.url
```

links.txt is a file containing a large number of urls, the problem happens with several large groups of urls that I have collected. It seems to me like that response objects may not be being deferenced?

I updated gevent, requests and grequests today, here are their versions:

```
In [2]: gevent.version_info
Out[2]: (1, 0, 0, 'beta', 3)

In [5]: requests.__version__
Out[5]: '0.13.5'
```

grequests doesn't have a version number that I could find.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: What happened if you let the script run till the end of the link list? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I've run across a different problem but in the same vein - the Response objects leave file handles open which will eventually result in resource exhaustion there.. Unsure if this is a **requests** or **grequests** problem. But I think I can see why the author of requests doesn't include grequests as part of the standard  module.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just an alias and link back for people who might need this [link](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/issues/18).

I use the imap function and requests.Session to reduce the memory usage while making 380k requests in my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it caused becouse you try to open all of the links at the same time. Try something like this:

```
links = set(links)
while links:
    calls = (grequests.get(links.pop()) for x in range(200)) 
    for r in calls:
        ...rest of your code
```

This code is not tested and you will find nicer soluution, this should be the proof that you simly try to open too many links at the same time and that causes your memory consumed.

Answer (score 0):

The project's requests library dependency should be updated.

Older versions of requests, including the one used in the question example, would not pre-fetch any response content by default, leaving it up to you to consume the data. This leaves open references to the underlying socket, so that even if the request session is garbage collected, the socket won't be garbage collected until the response goes out of scope or `response.content` is called.

In later versions of requests, responses are pre-fetched by default and session connections are closed explicitly if the session was created ad hoc for fulfilling a module-level `get`/`post`/etc request such as those made by grequests when a session isn't passed in. This is covered in [requests GitHub issue #520](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/520).